# Do .so files get loaded as a whole into memory?

Tags: memory, dynamic-linking

When a program causes a .so file to be loaded into memory, does is get loaded as a whole, or or does it only load the necessary "chunks"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. First the .so file is opened, then `mmap()` creates the virtual address space necessary to hold the whole file contents. However, only when something tries to access a particular address in the space will the access cause a page fault, and the kernel will read a (4k) block from the file corresponding to the page's offset into real memory. When it is in actual memory, the access will be restarted.  This is demand paging.

Comment: '... the kernel will read `PAGE_SIZE` block...' `PAGE_SIZE` depends on architecture

Comment: @Serge Sure, but all popular architectures use 4kB (and many obscure ones too).

Comment: @Gilles I commented for the sake of completeness, nothing else.